How does one split a PDF into individual pages with Preview
I would like to take a single 30-page PDF and split it so that it is 30 individual 1-page files (one file from each page of the original PDF).
I know that I have successfully done this in the past using Preview. For the life of me, I can not remember how it is done. I believe it was a matter of selecting the desired thumbnails and dragging them to the Finder (perhaps whilst holding down a key?) With this I keep getting a single PDF consisting of the selected pages.
Using this method, I can drag one page at a time, but this is very tedious. I do remember doing splitting a large file into pages in one stroke.

Alternative to drag-and-drop is doing it from the keyboard - select page(s) from thumbnails view, cmd+c to copy and cmd+n to paste into new file.

There's no way of doing this automatically in Preview.

Both Automator and Shortcuts have Split PDF actions that can be put into a workflow, which can be used as a Quick Action in the Finder.


While it annoys me that I can not find the solution that I previously used; this Workflow is an excellent option. I'm going to select this as correct, and chalk up my murky memories of manual PDF manipulation as early onset Macmentia.

You might also look at pdftk, which can split, and gives you control over the names of the resulting files.
